# Data Store clean up in unit test error - Only a single call to `runTest` can be performed during one test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-datastore

Getting the following error,

> Only a single call to `runTest` can be performed during one test.

In-unit tests for data store.

The issue is clearly because I have `runTest` in `@After` for data store cleanup after each test.

How do I fix this issue?

[Data store testing reference](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-testing-edf7ae8df3d8)

[Migrating from `runBlockingTest` to `runTest`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md)

Code

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyPreferencesDataSourceTest {
    private val testContext: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    private val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestScope(testDispatcher + Job())

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

    private val testDataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
        scope = testScope,
        produceFile = {
            testContext.preferencesDataStoreFile(
                name = AppConstants.APP_NAME,
            )
        },
    )

    private lateinit var appPreferenceDataSource: AppPreferenceDataSource

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        appPreferenceDataSource = AppPreferenceDataSource(
            dataStore = testDataStore,
        )
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() = testScope.runTest {
        testDataStore.edit {
            it.clear()
        }
        testScope.cancel()
    }

    @Test
    fun getCurrencyBase_returnsNull() = testScope.runTest {
        val result = appPreferenceDataSource.getData().first()

        Assert.assertNull(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not exactly what I was looking for, this is the best solution I could find so far.

I am open to better ways if there are any.

Source - [Kotlinlang Slack](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0B8M7BUY/p1693596858360469?thread_ts=1693591011.919689&cid=C0B8M7BUY)

With a little modification from the Slack message, I created this helper function.

```
private fun runTestAndCleanup(
    block: suspend () -> Unit,
) = testScope.runTest {
    block()
    testDataStore.edit {
        it.clear()
    }
}
```

And I replaced all the usages of `testScope.runTest` with `runTestAndCleanup`.

Answer (score 1):

Great question what you’re supposed to do if you have async stuff to run after or afterEach.

For this case you can try:

```
@After
fun teardown() {
    File(context.filesDir, "datastore").deleteRecursively()
}
```

Other wise there are more ideas here: [There are multiple DataStores active for the same file in HiltAndroidTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847060/there-are-multiple-datastores-active-for-the-same-file-in-hiltandroidtest)

Comment: Hi @ryankuck, Yes this solution works for this specific use-case. (clearing data from data store)